# How to apply on change event on a select box inside a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wrote some HTML as follows:

```
<div id = "dialog-1" title = "Dialog Title goes here...">
    <select id= "lang" name= "lang">
        <option value="1"> TEXT </option>
        <option value="2"> HTML </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to open a dialog box and apply `onChange()` event for select box to perform operations on selected value.

I am opening the dialog as follows :

```
$("#dialog-1").dialog({width: 600,height:500});
```

Now I want to perform On change() event on select box. I have tried as bellow but it doesn't work :

```
$("#dialog-1").dialog({
    var lang = $("#lang").val();
    alert("lang :: "+lang);
});
```

Comment: how are you opening the dialog box, using angularjs or jquery?

Comment: Read [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). The `select` directive is used together with [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to provide data-binding between the scope and the `<select>` control (including setting default values). It also handles dynamic <option> elements, which can be added using the `ngRepeat` or `ngOptions `directives.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to see all these tags in the question. Please clarify if you want to use a particular library/framework/plugin (jQuery, Angular etc) or you want to achieve the same with pure javascript.

Comment: I'm opening dialog using Jquery and after opening the dialog I want to handle on Change() event for select options.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really changes for your jQuery. You will need to assign a `.change()` callback on the `<select>` element. You can choose to be more specific if you wish.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-1").dialog({
    width: 600,
    height: 500
  });
  $("#dialog-1 #lang").change(function(e) {
    var lang = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    console.log("lang :: " + lang);
    $(this).parent().dialog("close");
  });
  $("a[rel='dialog']").button().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr("href")).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a href="#dialog-1" rel="dialog">Open Language Selection</a>
<div id="dialog-1" title="Select Language">
  <select id="lang" name="lang">
        <option value="1"> TEXT </option>
        <option value="2"> HTML </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's all about using the proper selector and proper callback function.

If the element is dynamically created, you can then use the `.on()` function.

```
$("#dialog-1").on("change", "select", function(){});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @AnilKadam I am glad it's working. You may like to upvote and mark this post as the selected answer.